# SQL query with multiple CTE but getting "ERROR: relation "t" does not exist"

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm trying to run a SQL query with multiple CTE but getting "ERROR:  relation "t" does not exist"

Here is the code. What am I doing wrong?

```
WITH tmp AS (
        Select a.tx_id, a.txo_index, a.address,b.tx_in_id from txo as a 
        inner join txin as b ON (a.tx_id = b.tx_out_id and a.txo_index= b.tx_out_index)
        where a.tx_in_id = 0
    ),
    tmp2 AS
    (
    Select tmp.tx_id,tmp.txo_index,tmp.address,tmp.tx_in_id,b.value as value_next,c.epoch_no as consumed_epoch,c.date as consumed_date from tmp
    inner join txo as b ON 
        tmp.tx_in_id  = b.tx_id and 
        tmp.address = b.address
    inner join tx as c ON 
        tmp.tx_in_id = c.id
    )
    Update t 
    SET 
        t.tx_in_id = tmp2.tx_in_id, 
        t.value_next = tmp2.value_next, 
        t.consumed_epoch = tmp2.epoch_no,
        t.consumed_date = tmp2.date
    FROM txo as t
    inner join tmp2 ON
        t.tx_id = tmp2.tx_id and t.txo_index = tmp2.txo_index and t.address = tmp2.address
    where t.tx_in_id =0
```

Comment: Are you using Postgresql?

Comment: Yes - am using Postgresl. Thinking I will have to put this into a function.

Comment: You are using SQL Server syntax on Postgres - that won't work

Comment: [Bad Habits to Kick : Using table aliases like (a, b, c) or (t1, t2, t3)](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-table-aliases-like-a-b-c-or-t1-t2-t3)   First you use b as alias for `txin`, and later on you use b as alias for `txo` 

Answer (score 1):

I believe referring to the table as an alias in the `UPDATE` and `SET` clause isn't allowed in postgres. Instead:

```
WITH tmp AS (
        Select a.tx_id, a.txo_index, a.address,b.tx_in_id from txo as a 
        inner join txin as b ON (a.tx_id = b.tx_out_id and a.txo_index= b.tx_out_index)
        where a.tx_in_id = 0
    ),
    tmp2 AS
    (
    Select tmp.tx_id,tmp.txo_index,tmp.address,tmp.tx_in_id,b.value as value_next,c.epoch_no as consumed_epoch,c.date as consumed_date from tmp
    inner join txo as b ON 
        tmp.tx_in_id  = b.tx_id and 
        tmp.address = b.address
    inner join tx as c ON 
        tmp.tx_in_id = c.id
    )
    Update txo
    SET 
        tx_in_id = tmp2.tx_in_id, 
        value_next = tmp2.value_next, 
        consumed_epoch = tmp2.epoch_no,
        consumed_date = tmp2.date
    FROM  tmp2 
    WHERE txo.tx_id = tmp2.tx_id 
        and txo.txo_index = tmp2.txo_index 
        and txo.address = tmp2.address
        and txo.tx_in_id =0
```

Comment: hmm thanks, are you sure I don't need the join in that Update? That's what was giving me issues when I didn't have an Alias.

Comment: @user1761806: the "join" is done in the WHERE clause

Comment: Ok thanks, I'll have to do some tests to convince myself it's the exact same as doing a join. I'm worried it'll inadvertently be picking up a txo table relationship from earlier up the query.